# How do I refactor if else statements of API calls?

Tags: javascript, angular, refactoring

I have a search button and depending upon the selected option from a user, the corresponding API call will be triggered. But I have now a bunch of if else statements.

So my question is, can I refactor this? But without a switch case?

```
 searchFor() {
    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      this.extendedSearchService
        .filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue, this.startDate)
        .subscribe(filterByRegistration => {
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByRegistration);
        });
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Chat') {
      this.extendedSearchService.filterByChat(this.startDate).subscribe(filterByChat => {
        this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByChat);
      });
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Inlog') {
      console.log('INlog');
      this.extendedSearchService.filterByInlog(this.startDate).subscribe(filterByInlog => {
        this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByInlog);
      });
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'QrCode') {
      this.extendedSearchService
        .filterByQrCodes(this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedQrcode)
        .subscribe(fitlerByQrCode => {
          this.filterparticipant.emit(fitlerByQrCode);
        });
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Doelen') {
      this.extendedSearchService
        .filerByChallenge(this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedValueOptie, this.selectedValueProgressie)
        .subscribe(filterByChallenge => {
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByChallenge);
        });
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Vcheq') {
      this.extendedSearchService
        .filterByVchecCode(this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedVcheqOption)
        .subscribe(filterByVcheqCode => {
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByVcheqCode);
        });
    }
  }
```

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
 searchFor() {
    const filter = (method, params) => {
      this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
        this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
      });

      const filters = {
        Registratie: filter('Registratie', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate]),
        Chat: filter('Chat', [this.startDate]),
        Inlog: filter('Inlog', this.startDate),
        QrCode: filter('QrCode', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedQrcode]),
        Doelen: filter('Doelen', [
          this.selectedValue,
          this.startDate,
          this.selectedValueOptie,
          this.selectedValueProgressie
        ]),
        Vcheq: filter('Vcheq', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedVcheqOption])
      };

      if (filters[this.selectedSearch]) {
        filters[this.selectedSearch]();
      }
    };
}
```

And it compiles, but the filter doesnt work.

if I do this:

```
 searchFor() {
    const filter = (method, params) => {
      this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
        console.log('Filter');
        this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
      });
    };
```

I get this error:

```
ExtendedSearchComponent.html:90 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at filter (extended-search.component.ts:211)
    at
```

On this line:

```
 this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
        console.log('Filter');
```

I have it so:

```
searchFor() {

      const filter = (method, params) => {
        this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
          console.log(method);
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
        });
      };

      const filters = {
        Registratie: filter('filterByRegistration', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate]),
        Chat: filter('filterByChat', [this.startDate]),
        Inlog: filter('filterByInlog', [this.startDate]),
        QrCode: filter('filterByQrCodes', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedQrcode]),
        Doelen: filter('filerByChallenge', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedValueOptie, this.selectedValueProgressie]),
        Vcheq: filter('filterByVchecCode', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedVcheqOption]),
     }

      if (filters[this.selectedSearch]) {
        filters[this.selectedSearch]();
      }
    }
```

Then I get this error:

```
ExtendedSearchComponent.html:88 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at filter (extended-search.component.ts:213)
    at ExtendedSearchComponent.push../src/app/participant/components/extended-search/extended-search.component.ts.ExtendedSearchComponent.searchFor (extended-search.component.ts:220)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ExtendedSearchComponent.html:91)
    at handleEvent (core.js:19628)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:20722)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:20425)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:17077)
    at core.js:17524
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
```

Oke, I did some debugging.

and put this:

```
 console.log('Method', method);
```

But then I see that multiple methods are been called:

```
Method filterByRegistration
extended-search.component.ts:214 Method filterByInlog
extended-search.component.ts:214 Method filterByChat
```

What of course not has to been. Just one api call at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lastest version of code in the post calls `filter` six times when initializing `const filters`. However  `filter` should only be called once in the `if` statement at the end of `searchFor`.

One way of achieving this is to record both the method name and parameters in the `filters` object and modify `filter` to pick up both the method and its parameters. For example:

```
function searchFor() {

  const filter = (using) => {
    this.extendedSearchService[using.method](...using.params).subscribe(filter => {
      console.log(using.method);
      this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
    });
  };

  const filters = {
    Registratie: { method: 'filterByRegistration', params: [this.selectedValue, this.startDate]},
    Chat: { method: 'filterByChat', params: [this.startDate]},
    Inlog: { method: 'filterByInlog', params:  [this.startDate]},
    QrCode:{ method: 'filterByQrCodes', params: [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedQrcode]},
    Doelen: { method: 'filerByChallenge', params: [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedValueOptie, this.selectedValueProgressie]},
    Vcheq: { method: 'filterByVchecCode', params: [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedVcheqOption]},
  }

  if (filters[this.selectedSearch]) {
    filter(filters[this.selectedSearch]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you traktor53. But I get this error: filter[this.selectedSearch] is not a function
    at ExtendedSearchComponent.push../src/app/participant/components/extended-search/extended-search.component.ts.ExtendedSearchComponent.searchFor (extended-search.component.ts:230)

Comment: I try it like this:  console.log( filter[this.selectedSearch](filters).join(''));

Comment: @mightycodeNewton updated per your comment - that was the intention, but I missed it without being able to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object with the property as the search type and the function as the value.

This is an example of how it works

```js
var searchObject = {
  optionA: function(){
    console.log('Option A')
  },
  optionB: function(){
    console.log('Option B')
  }
}

function search(option){
  searchObject[option]()
}

search('optionA')
search('optionB')
```

And this is a snippet of what your code would look *like*, I haven't kept up with angular so it might be `this.searchObject` depending on where you define it, but the concept would be the same

```
var searchObject = {
  Registratie: function() {
    this.extendedSearchService
      .filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue, this.startDate)
      .subscribe(filterByRegistration => {
        this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByRegistration);
      });
  },
  Chat: function() {
    this.extendedSearchService.filterByChat(this.startDate).subscribe(filterByChat => {
      this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByChat);
    });
  }
}



searchFor() {
  searchObject[this.selectedSearch]()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made something dynamic, this way you avoid checking one by one

```
const filter = (method, params) => {
  this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
     this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
  });
};

const filters = {
   Registratie: filter('filterByRegistration', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate]),
   Chat: filter('filterByChat', [this.startDate]),
   Inlog: filter('filterByInlog', [this.startDate]),
   QrCode: filter('filterByQrCodes', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedQrcode]),
   Doelen: filter('filerByChallenge', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedValueOptie, this.selectedValueProgressie]),
   Vcheq: filter('filterByVchecCode', [this.selectedValue, this.startDate, this.selectedVcheqOption]),
}

if(filters[this.selectedSearch]) {
   filters[this.selectedSearch]();
}
```

Comment: Haven't test it, but in fact is the approach you should follow for avoid conditioning.

Comment: The methods names you post are not the same as mines. Method name is `filterByChat ` or `Chat`? Could you log into `filter()` console.log(this.extendedSearchService[method]) should be a function, currently doesn't exist, you cannot execute that `undefined()`

Comment: if I do this: const filter = (method, params) => {
        this.extendedSearchService[method](...params).subscribe(filter => {
          console.log(method);
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filter);
        }); the console.log is not shown. thrown error